# Control OS mouse clicks

Tags: c++, windows, operating-system

I can't seem to find what I am looking for which is a way to alter the OS's mouse clicks. To specify this would be on Windows.

The goal is to limit the number of mouse clicks a user can register within a period of time.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Well the example isn't why I want to use it. My mouse is broken, it will randomly register double clicks instead of a single click so I want to limit the number of mouse clicks registered by the os to be at least `x` time apart.

Comment: Why don't you just change the mouse click speed in the Windows settings?

Comment: That doesn't do anything, the left mouse button has a hardware issue that registers clicks almost instantly after the other. If I was to delay the mouse clicks being registered by the os by even a milisecond, I am sure it would fix the issue.

Comment: Register a [low-level mouse hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986.aspx), and filter out messages you do not want to be passed on to the system. But seriously, unless your time has absolutely zero value, consider buying a mouse that works.

Comment: Cool I'll check this out, thanks. Yeah the ultimate end is to swap it out but it is a fun way to learn more about manipulating the OS in a practical way.

Comment: It's more fun manipulating the OS with a working mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I think the function that you are looking for is `SetWindowsHookEx`. Here is a quick example.

```
#include <windows.h>

const DWORD desireddelay = 10;

LRESULT CALLBACK MouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static DWORD previoustimestamp = 0;
    if ((nCode == 0) && (wParam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN))
    {
        if ((((MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam)->time - previoustimestamp) < desireddelay)
        {
            return 1; //Non-Zero Swallows the keystroke. 0 Allows it. Always CallNextHookEx if you are not swallowing it.
        }
        else
        {
            previoustimestamp = ((MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam)->time;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseProc, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    MSG msg;
    bool done = false;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {}
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is really not an answer to the question. It's almost a link-only answer, too, but without a link. Either make this into a full answer, or delete it.

Comment: Note that if you're *not* swallowing the click, you should always call CallNextHookEx, not return 0.

Comment: The timestamp filter uses the wrong timestamps. You don't want to base the filter on the time you are processing the message. You should use the timestamp when the message was generated instead. This is available through the [MSLLHOOKSTRUCT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644970.aspx) passed as the *lParam*. `prevtime` should be a static variable, local to the `MouseProc`, too.